# Swapping content of an array list

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, swap

Hi i need to swap content of 3 arraylist at the same time but im having an error.

```
//This is my methods
public void reorder(int a, int b){
    Collections.swap(trackNum,a,b);
    Collections.swap(name,a,b);
    Collections.swap(duration,a,b);
}

//This is me using the methods
case 3:
    meth.print();
    System.out.println("What is the first index you would like to swap:"); 
        meth.reorder(in.nextInt());
    System.out.println("What is the second index you would like to swap:");
        meth.reorder(in.nextInt());
    break;
```

Can someone please explain where i went wrong.

The error msg im getting is "The method reorder(int, int) in the type methods is not applicable for the arguments (int)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method call doesn't match the signature. You're only passing a single int where you should be passing two.

```
public void reorder(int a, int b){ ... } // Here you specify two arguments.
...
meth.reorder(in.nextInt()); // Here you only pass one.
```

```
//This is me using the methods
case 3:
    meth.print();
    System.out.println("What is the first index you would like to swap:"); 
    int first = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the second index you would like to swap:");
    int second = in.nextInt();
    meth.reorder(first, second);
    break;
```

Comment: How would i do that, sorry im a beginner

Comment: You just put another integer argument in the call.

Comment: How do i add another integer argument to the call

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing wrong is you are using multiple collection when you should have one type which has all the fields you need and a single collection of all this information.

> Im getting the error, "The method reorder(int, int) in the type methods is not applicable for the arguments (int)"

In that case, you only want to reorder once, and only when you have all the information. i.e. you need two numbers.

I suggest you save the first value into a variable and only call reorder() once you have the second value as well.

```
System.out.println("What is the first index you would like to swap:"); 
int a = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("What is the second index you would like to swap:");
int b = in.nextInt();
meth.reorder(a, b);
```

Comment: Im getting the error, "The method reorder(int, int) in the type methods is not applicable for the arguments (int)"